# Why can't I cast itertools.chain object to list in Jython

Tags: python, jython

In Python:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(['aaa','bbb']))
```

gives:

```
['a','a','a','b','b','b']
```

as expected.
In Jython 2.7.0 the same code gives `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

Note that it seems to be the attempt to cast to a list that gives the error, as

```
for c in itertools.chain.from_iterable(['aaa','bbb']):
     lst.append(c)
```

constructs the required list.

Comment: Pedantic: You're not "casting", you're _constructing_ a new `list`, the constructor takes an iterable and exhausts it to make the new `list`. Python doesn't have casting as a language concept (some libraries do, but they're usually low-level interface libraries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there is no problem with Jython, you just declared a variable named `list` and assigned it a string value.

Run `del list` to get rid of the name shadowing the built-in, then retry, and it should work on Jython too.

Comment: Works for me too now I have restarted the interpreter. Next time I'll use `dir()` to check if I accidentally added a variable. Thanks.